# android - list view in center of relative layout

Tags: android

I have the following layout (`Android 4.4`):

```
<RelativeLayout       
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"  
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The list view doesn't show up in the center. What am I missing ?

[image]

ListView item layout :

```
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@+id/label"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:background="@color/list_background"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit** :

1. Even if I set the list view width to wrap_content, it doesn't make a difference.
2. Changing outer view to LinearLayout doesn't help.

Comment: its already matching the parent width so there is no way to center it horizontally

Comment: use LinearLayout instead of relative layout

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin made a second edit

Comment: @Jake post your listview item layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `List Item Layout` to center the views horizontally.

**sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/labIcon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lawl"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="item1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't resolve your issue, but

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**You shouldn't use `wrap_content` for the height of a ListView**.

In this way your `ListView` must measure its items and to get the items it has to call `getView()` on the Adapter. This causes that the `getView()` method is called several times in an inefficient way.